# How to append the last motify date to a FileName suffix when cp a File

Tags: linux, shell

I want to append  the last **motify date** to a FileName which will be copyed
I just know how to append the **current date** to a File,like:

```
 find -name *.log  -exec cp {} {}__$(date "+%F")__bak \;
```

and test.log --> test.log__2012.12.24__bak

I want test.log --> test.log__{last_mofigy_date}__bak

But how can I append the **last modify date** to the fileName ,it is best if it can be done in one statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
$ for file in $(find .  -name *.log )
> do
>  x=$(stat -c %y $file)
>  echo cp $file ${file}_${x%% *}_bak
> done
```

This snippet will display the set of `cp` commands formed. If it is proper, remove the echo and run it to get the files copied.

**Updated:**
Another way using just find and exec :

```
 find . -name *.log -exec bash -c 'x={} ; y=$(stat -c %y $x); echo cp $x ${x}_${y%% *}_bak ' \;
```

Comment: This can be OK ,but can you just find a solution to do it in just one statement,like:

                                                         
    find -name *.log  -exec cp {} {}__$(????????)__bak \;

Comment: @mainlove : Updated the solution like you expected